# Express all issue

Tags: express

I docs it said that this two way of defining two sequential midlewares are equivalent

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.all

```
app.all('*', requireAuthentication, loadUser);
```

Or the equivalent:

```
app.all('*', requireAuthentication)
app.all('*', loadUser);
```

But it if we have middlewares defined as:

```
var requireAuthentication = function(req, res, next){
  req.params.someParam = 1
  next()
}

var loadUser = function(req, res, next){
  console.log('someParam', req.params.someParam)
  ...
}
```

In first case `req.params.someParam` inside loadUser will be 1, and in second case it will be `undefined`.

Is it a bug or wat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short: `req.params` doesn't persist across routes. Use `res.locals` instead.**

Not a bug in Express, but not very intuitive. This is a good question!

`req.params` is for grabbing parameters out of a URL. For example, if you had a route defined like this...

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.send('user id == ' + req.params.id);
});
```

...and you visited `/user/123`, then `req.params.id` would be `"123"`.

This `params` property is *different for every route*. Take a look at this example:

```
app.get('/user/:userid', function(req, res, next) {
  // req.params.userid is defined in here
  // req.params.id is NOT defined here
  next();
});

app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
  // req.params.id is defined in here
  // req.params.userid is NOT defined here
});
```

`req.params` isn't the same for every route, which explains what you're seeing.

Your first example has *one* route with two request handler functions, so they all have access to the same `req.params` object. Your second example has *two* routes with two request handler functions, so they're accessing different `req.params` objects.

If you're trying to persist data between different request handler functions across the same request, you should use [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.locals). To rewrite your example:

```
var requireAuthentication = function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.someParam = 1
  next()
}

var loadUser = function(req, res, next){
  console.log('someParam', res.locals.someParam)
  ...
}
```

Using `res.locals` will work whether you have one line or two.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about res.locals)